# App crashes if I apply a CIFilter to a CIImage - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, crash, ram, core-image

I have this strange problem I can't solve. If I take a picture with my app and apply a CIFilter to it everything works fine, but if I take another picture and apply the same filter my app crashes without any error. But strangely I can do the same process with a image from my camera roll and the app works perfectly fine.

```
//CAMERA

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var selectedImage: UIImage!    

@IBAction func rollButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func cameraButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera){

        let camera = UIImagePickerController()
        camera.delegate = self
        camera.allowsEditing = false
        camera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        camera.showsCameraControls = true

        camera.cameraOverlayView?.layer.borderWidth = 3
        camera.cameraOverlayView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        camera.cameraOverlayView?.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.minX, self.view.frame.midY - self.view.frame.width/8, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.width/4)


        self.presentViewController(camera, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    selectedImage = (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage)

    for var i = 2; i <= 10; i++ {
        imageView.image = processImage(selectedImage, colors: i)
    }

}
```

The function that is causing the problems:

```
let context = CIContext(options: nil)

func processImage(image: UIImage, colors: Int) -> UIImage{

    var img1:CIImage = CIImage(image: image)!
    img1 = img1.imageByApplyingFilter("CIPhotoEffectMono", withInputParameters:["inputImage" : img1])
    img1 = img1.imageByApplyingFilter("CISharpenLuminance", withInputParameters: ["inputImage" : img1])
    img1 = img1.imageByApplyingFilter("CIColorPosterize", withInputParameters: ["inputImage" : img1, "inputLevels" : colors])
    img1 = img1.imageByApplyingFilter("CIColorControls", withInputParameters: ["inputImage" : img1, "inputSaturation" : 1, "inputBrightness": 0.2, "inputContrast": 1.5 //8
        ])
    img1 = img1.imageByApplyingFilter("CIHighlightShadowAdjust", withInputParameters: ["inputImage" : img1, "inputHighlightAmount": 6, "inputShadowAmount": 0])
    img1 = img1.imageByApplyingFilter("CIColorPosterize", withInputParameters: ["inputImage" : img1, "inputLevels" : 3])


    let cgImg = context.createCGImage(img1, fromRect: img1.extent)

    let uiImg = UIImage(CGImage: cgImg, scale: 1.0, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
    print("x")
    return uiImg
}
```

I've looked at the RAM usage and if I use a image from the camera my app uses about 40% and the it crashes, but if I select a image from my camera roll I only get a max. of 8% of RAM usage.

If you know why, I would be very happy if you could leave an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to add `image = UIImage(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9)!)!` at the beginning of `processImage`, because I the Image was to big.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting out of memory because of `createCGImage`.

Working for me `processImage` function:

```
func processImage(image: UIImage, colors: Int) -> UIImage{
    var img1:CIImage = CIImage(image: image)!
    img1 = img1.imageByApplyingFilter("CIPhotoEffectMono", withInputParameters:["inputImage" : img1])
    img1 = img1.imageByApplyingFilter("CISharpenLuminance", withInputParameters: ["inputImage" : img1])
    img1 = img1.imageByApplyingFilter("CIColorPosterize", withInputParameters: ["inputImage" : img1, "inputLevels" : colors])
    img1 = img1.imageByApplyingFilter("CIColorControls", withInputParameters: ["inputImage" : img1, "inputSaturation" : 1, "inputBrightness": 0.2, "inputContrast": 1.5 //8
        ])
    img1 = img1.imageByApplyingFilter("CIHighlightShadowAdjust", withInputParameters: ["inputImage" : img1, "inputHighlightAmount": 6, "inputShadowAmount": 0])
    img1 = img1.imageByApplyingFilter("CIColorPosterize", withInputParameters: ["inputImage" : img1, "inputLevels" : 3])

    let uiImg = UIImage(CIImage: img1)
    print("x")
    return uiImg ?? UIImage()
}
```

And I would make the returning UIImage type optional. You never know if it would be processed. Better to check.

Comment: One problem. If i do `imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(processImage(selectedImage!, colors: 2))`  `imageData` is nil.